# How to embed forms to another website using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I have a two projects using laravel framework. I have a form for project 1 that I want to embed on my project 2.

Here is my FormController in project 1

```
public function show(Form $form)
{
  
    return view('formbuilder.render', compact('form'))->render();
}
```

View on project 2 where I want to embed the form on project 1

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
   div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://route/for/first-project-form"></script>
      </div>
   </div>
                        
@endsection
```

I want to imitate how jot form works. https://www.jotform.com/help/34-Embedding-a-Form-to-a-Web-Page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can give it a try like: return view('formBuilder.render',compact('form'))->render()

Comment: you could just to it via an iframe, but if you want really go script tag you'll need to render a js then js loads the form, in which case just use a iframe, much simpler

Comment: @NaveedAli I forgot to add the render() method. But it seems does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your response. For now I will be using the script tag and later will be adding the i-frame.  Can you give example on this "script tag you'll need to render a js then js loads the form"?

Comment: You need to create a javascript file that creates an iframe on the page and loads your project 1 form there. But it's so much easier to do it using an iframe directly..

Comment: @Jearson https://form.jotform.com/jsform/202301621319441 here's what jotform does under the hood, they create an iframe using js including a bunch of stuff im not sure you'd like to do those codes in there. i'd suggest keep it simple.

Comment: @gbalduzzi Thank you for your input. I already implemented the iframe. Yeah it is much easier. However, I need to embed the form using iframe and script.

Comment: I edited my answer to create the iframe using javascript

Comment: @gbalduzzi Appreciate your help. It's not that I do not want to use the iframe but we want to give another option for embedding forms.

Answer (score 3):

Using an iframe it's just this simple:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
   div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
          <iframe src="https://route/for/first-project-form"></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>                        
@endsection
```

If you really want to use a javascript file to load the iframe (can't see any reason why, but let's do it):

Create  a javascript file:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('form-container')
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://route/for/first-project-form");
iframe.style.width = "640px";
iframe.style.height = "480px";
container.appendChild(iframe);
```

In project 2:

```
@section('content')
   <div class="card rounded-0">
      <div class="card-body">
          <div id="form-container"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="http//link/to/javascript/file"></script>                
@endsection
```